# Maven + Hudson + Nexus: Access to SNAPSHOT Build Number

Tags: maven, hudson, nexus, snapshot

Now that Maven3 has dropped support for setting uniqueVersion=false on deployment, I'm running into an issue.  I have Hudson do an automatic deployment of my SNAPSHOT build to my Nexus repository manager.  The resulting SNAPSHOT artifact looks like blah-0.0.1-20110517.233746-1.jar.  Note the unique SNAPSHOT build id.  The trick is that I'd link to that jar in my site documentation, but I'm not sure how to inject that snapshot build number into the docs.  Perhaps there is a way to have Maven or Hudson or Nexus create a symlink on deployment from blah-0.0.1.jar => blah-0.0.1-20110517.233746-1.jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, mod me down, but I think I found an answer to my own question.  I'm posting here in case anyone else finds it useful.

It turns out the Nexus REST api has the ability to automatically retrieve the latest SNAPSHOT build of an artifact, which is exactly the functionality I needed.  For more info, see:

https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Nexus+FAQ#NexusFAQ-Q.HowcanIretrieveasnapshotifIdon%27tknowtheexactfilename%3F

Comment: Above links is asking for credential ...@Brian can you please check ...